# Python: how to create a server to supervise a thread pool?

Tags: python, networking, python-asyncio

I have a thread pool that handles some tasks concurrently. Now I'd like the tasks (`multiply_by_2` here) to print something before exit.

Originally, I created a lock and passed the lock to each worker thread. If a thread wants to print something, it first acquires the lock, prints its message to stdout, then releases the lock.

Now, I want to have a dedicated **event-driven** server thread to handle the printing. If a thread wants to print something, it just send its message to that server, via a Unix domain socket (`AF_UNIX`). I hope in this way, each thread's blocking time can be reduced (no need to wait for the lock) and I don't need to share a lock among worker threads. The server thread just prints whatever messages it got from clients (i.e. the worker threads) in order.

I tried for some time with Python's `asyncio` module (requiring Python 3.7+) but couldn't figure it out. How should I do it?

This cleaned-up template is:

```
# Python 3.7+
import asyncio
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp # Threading wrapped using multiprocessing API.
import os
import socket
import sys
import threading
import time

server_address = './uds_socket' # UNIX domain socket

def run_multiple_clients_until_complete(input_list):
    pool = mp.Pool(8)
    result_list = pool.map(multiply_by_2, input_list)
    return result_list

def multiply_by_2(n):
    time.sleep(0.2) # Simulates some blocking call.
    message_str = "client: n = %d" % n
    
    # TODO send message_str.encode() to server

    return n * 2

# Server's callback when it gets a client connection
# If you want to change it, please do..
def client_connected_cb(
    stream_reader: asyncio.StreamReader,
    stream_writer: asyncio.StreamWriter) -> None:
    message_str = reader.read().decode()
    print(message_str)

def create_server_thread():
    pass # TODO

# Let the server finish handling all connections it got, then
# stop the server and join the thread
def stop_server_and_wait_thread(thread):
    pass # TODO

def work(input_list):
    thread = create_server_thread()
    result_list = run_multiple_clients_until_complete(input_list)
    stop_server_and_wait_thread(thread)
    return result_list

def main():
    input_list = list(range(20))
    result_list = work(input_list)
    print(result_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Some extra requirements:

- Don't make `async`: `run_multiple_clients_until_complete()`, `multiply_by_2()`, `main()`.
- It would be nicer to use the `SOCK_DGRAM` UDP protocol instead of `SOCK_STREAM` TCP, but it's unnecessary.

Comment: Asyncio is not a good fit for managing blocking code. Also, an async program is typically async from the ground up, so not allowing `main()` to be async is somewhat of a non-starter. (There are ways around it, but they're not simple, and it's not clear they'd help here.) It is also not clear what exactly is wrong with the current solution - if the lock makes things too slow, it's hard to imagine that asyncio, which is completely single-threaded, will makes things faster.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks, could you make it an answer so I can accept it? You are right, I was looking for a way to get around "async program is typically async from the ground up", and it turns out there's no idiomatic solution.